# retrieving some AngularJS object value

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to `AngularJS`, suppose I have

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="todo in todos">
     <span> ...</span>
```

where each `todo` is some object, let's say {"title": "some title", "description":"some description"}. I want now to retrieve the whole value of this `todo` when some change event happens inside the `span` tag. Sorry by advance if it is too simple...

Comment: can you be more accurate, you want to be notified when your "todo" object changes?

Comment: @AlexChoroshin. I have edited my post. In fact I want to retrieve the value of the whole `todo` object

Comment: @user1611830 what kind of change are we talking about like input change? or something else?

Comment: not really, in fact I use some query plugin that creates on the fly some div's whose content will update todo's one

Answer (score 0):

The easiest and most straightforward way of doing that is:

```
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="todo in todos">
         <span>{{todo.title}}</span>
         <span>{{todo.description}}</span>
         <input type="text" ng-model="todo" />
```

Note that I added a Input text field just to showcase that when you assign objects to directive's attributes, you don't surround your angular objects with double curly braces.

Comment: I have edited my post. In fact I want to retrieve the value of the whole todo object

Answer (score 0):

If the span is causing the event, you can do something like this...

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="todo in todos">
        <span ng-click="doSomething(todo)"> ...</span>
```

Comment: I don't want tot click anything

Comment: Be more specific with the issue.  What is "some change event happens"?

Comment: I just want the most simple thing, get back the todo object value

Answer (score 0):

You can always use [$watch](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/%24rootScope.Scope#%24watch) and Register a listener callback to be executed whenever your  scope (object) changes.

Example:

html:

```
<div ng-app="App"  ng-controller="ctrl">
<div>
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="todo in todos">
          <span><input type="text" ng-model="todo.title">{{todo.title}}</span>
      </li>
    <ui>
        my event : {{myEvent}}
</div>
```

js:

```
var app=angular.module('App', []);

function ctrl($scope) {
    $scope.myEvent="";
    $scope.todos = [
              {"title": "some title1", "description":"some description1"},
              {"title": "some title2", "description":"some description2"},
              {"title": "some title3", "description":"some description3"}
                    ]
    $scope.$watch('todos', function (newVal) {
        $scope.myEvent=newVal;
    }, true);

 }
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/choroshin/vLJ92/

Comment: that's not really what I am trying to find.  in fact I use some query plugin that creates on the fly some div's whose content will update todo's one. I want a way to fetch the whole todo object. Isn't it possible, (by something as data-attributes)

Answer (score 0):

if you want to make changes to the object its better to use input elements rather than span tags, there is directive ['ng-change'](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange) which will trigger a change whenever user changes the content, see this plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/HQgGB1HRAjUE7EVxiJZ5?p=preview

Comment: I don't want to do any change to `todo` value, I only want to fetch the value of the `todo`

Comment: I believe that he wants to listen to any change in the Todos array.
Check my answer.

Comment: @user1611830 when do you want to fetch the todo value ?